# Print sorted output with awk to avoid pipe sort command

Tags: awk

I'm trying to match the lines containing `(123)` and then manipulate field 2 replacing `x` and `+` by space that will give 4 columns. Then change order of column 3 by Column 4.
To finally print sorted first by column 3 and second by column 4.

I'm able to get the output piping `sort` command after `awk` output in this way.

```sh
$ echo "
0:   1920x1663+0+0     kpwr(746)
323: 892x550+71+955    kpwr(746)
211: 891x550+1003+410  kpwr(746)
210: 892x451+71+410    kpwr(746)
415: 891x451+1003+1054 kpwr(746)
1:   894x532+70+330    kpwr(123)
324: 894x532+1001+975  kpwr(123)
2:   894x631+1001+330  kpwr(123)
212: 894x631+70+876    kpwr(123)
61:  892x1+71+375      kpwr(0)
252: 892x1+71+921      kpwr(0)" | 
awk '/\(123\)/{b = gensub(/(.+)x(.+)\+(.+)\+(.+)/, "\\1 \\2 \\4 \\3", "g", $2); print b}' |  
sort -k3 -k4 -n

894 532 330 70
894 631 330 1001
894 631 876 70
894 532 975 1001
```

How can I get the same output using only awk without the need to pipe `sort`? Thanks for any help.

Comment: You are better off piping to `sort`. `awk` doesn't have any great sorting abilities since the arrays in `awk` are associative. `awk` is the correct tool for manipulating the column data as you need, but `sort` is the proper tool to reorder the lines afterwards.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is how you can get it from `awk` (gnu) itself:

```
awk '/\(123\)/{
   $2 = gensub(/(.+)x(.+)\+(.+)\+(.+)/, "\\1 \\2 \\4 \\3", "g", $2)
   split($2, a)           # split by space and store into array a
   # store array by index 3 and 4
   rec[a[3]][a[4]] = (rec[a[3]][a[4]] == "" ? "" : rec[a[3]][a[4]] ORS) $2
}
END { 
   PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@ind_num_asc" # sort by numeric key ascending
   for (i in rec)         # print stored array rec
      for (j in rec[i])
         print rec[i][j]
}' file
```

```
894 532 330 70
894 631 330 1001
894 631 876 70
894 532 975 1001
```

Comment: Is it just my eyes or does that code font just turn italic?

Comment: Actually first I thought it is my eyes only that are seeing italics :)  But I wonder why?

Comment: Ah, no, this is the syntax highlighting misidentifying your awk code as something that’s marked up with HLJS emphasis. A different code tag will fix that.

Comment: Thanks so much @MartijnPieters I had never used `none` in code tag before.

Answer (score 3):

Can you handle GNU awk?:

```
$ gawk '
BEGIN {
    PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@val_num_asc"              # for order strategy
}
/\(123\)$/ {                                          # pick records
    split($2,t,/[+x]/)                                # split 2nd field
    if((t[4] in a) && (t[3] in a[t[4]])) {            # if index collision
        n=split(a[t[4]][t[3]],u,ORS)                  # split stacked element
        u[n+1]=t[1] OFS t[2] OFS t[4] OFS t[3]        # add new data
        delete a[t[4]][t[3]]                          # del before rebuilding
        for(i in u)                                   # sort on whole record
            a[t[4]][t[3]]=a[t[4]][t[3]] ORS u[i]      # restack to element
    } else
        a[t[4]][t[3]]=t[1] OFS t[2] OFS t[4] OFS t[3] # no collision, just add
}
END {
    PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@ind_num_asc"              # strategy on output

    for(i in a)           
        for(j in a[i])
            print a[i][j]
}' file
```

Output:

```
894 532 330 70
894 631 330 1001
894 631 876 70
894 532 975 1001
```

With collisioning data like:

```
1:   894x532+70+330    kpwr(123)  # this 
1:   123x456+70+330    kpwr(123)  # and this, notice order
324: 894x532+1001+975  kpwr(123)
2:   894x631+1001+330  kpwr(123)
212: 894x631+70+876    kpwr(123)
```

output would be:

```
123 456 330 70                    # ordered by the whole record when collision
894 532 330 70
894 631 330 1001
894 631 876 70
894 532 975 1001
```

Comment: @JamesBrown Thanks for you solution and explanation, it helps a lot to understand the code. It works showing correct output.

Comment: Your previous code adding the `1:   123x456+70+330    kpwr(123)` gave me repetead lines in output.  I see that you modified you code and now the output is correct. Thanks so much for let us know about that issue.

Comment: Yeah, I forgot to reset the element in `a[][]` before rebuilding. Sorry about that.

Comment: No problem. Thanks a lot for your help. I'm not sure which solution would be the better, since I'm not expert. I've chosen anubhava's because is shorter. That was my criteria. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I was almost done with writing and my solution was ditto as @anubhava's so adding a bit tweak to his solution :) This one will take care of multiple lines of same values here.

```
awk '
BEGIN{
  PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@ind_num_asc"
}
/\(123\)/{
   $2 = gensub(/(.+)x(.+)\+(.+)\+(.+)/, "\\1 \\2 \\4 \\3", "g", $2)
   split($2, a," ")
   arr[a[3]][a[4]] = (arr[a[3]][a[4]]!=""?arr[a[3]][a[4]] ORS:"")$2
}
END { 
   for (i in arr){
      for (j in arr[i]){ print arr[i][j] }
   }
}' Input_file
```

Comment: Thanks so  much for your solution and feature to handle multiple lines with same values.

Comment: Very good point Ravinder for handling multiple values for same key.

Comment: Just a minor point that `val == ""` is better check for an empty string in `awk`. Just checking for `val` returns false if it is equal to zero.

Comment: @anubhava, sure sir, is it looking good now sir, kindly confirm once sir.